# When I divide a vector by a scalar how do we divide a direction by a scalar?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, vectors

Suppose I divide the net displacement vector of an object by time taken to get the average velocity vector. The displacement vector has both magnitude and direction. How do I divide direction by the time taken?

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a vector as an arrow. Dividing it by a number we call $t$ produces a $t$ times shorter arrow that still points towards the same direction. So the conclusion is that when you divide a Vector by a scalar you don't act on the direction of the vector, you only act on its magnitude.

Comment: how is vector an arrow a vector is a quantity and it is divided by a  scalar quantity not a number

Comment: @Sandeep Gulati A vector is an arrow, and a scalar is a number, for your purposes a real number, since you're dividing by the time. Look at this Wikipedia page, it may help: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector

Answer (score 2):

No, dividing a displacement vector with a scalar **does not change the direction** but **only the magnitude** (this holds true for the typical Cartesian coordinate systems with purely spatial coordinates).

Such a vector could be:

$$
   \left(\begin{matrix}
   30\;\mathrm{m} \\
   40 \;\mathrm{m}
   \end{matrix}\right)
$$

which means "*10 meters forward (along one axis) and 20 meters sideways (along the other axis)*". If you divide this vector by 2 and get

$$
   \left(\begin{matrix}
   30\;\mathrm{m} \\
   40 \;\mathrm{m}
   \end{matrix}\right)/\;2=
   \left(\begin{matrix}
   15\;\mathrm{m} \\
   20 \;\mathrm{m}
   \end{matrix}\right)
$$

then both **coordinates** have changes with the same ratio (both are halved) and the direction is the same. Because it doesn't matter if you go *5 meters out and 5 meters up* or *1 meter out and 1 meter up*; the direction is the same. Only the magnitude changed.

### Mathematics

If you have any vector of the form we are talking about

$$
   \left(\begin{matrix}
   a \\
   b
   \end{matrix}\right)
$$

you can calculate it's magnitude with the so-called Pythagoras' theorem:
$$\text{length}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

With the examples above, the magnitudes become:

$$\text{length}=\sqrt{(30\;\mathrm{m})^2+(40\;\mathrm{m})^2}=50\;\mathrm{m}\\
\text{length}=\sqrt{(15\;\mathrm{m})^2+(20\;\mathrm{m})^2}=25\;\mathrm{m}$$

You can also calculate the directions (if you imagine it as an angle in a coordinate system) with some sneaky triangle math:

$$\text{angle}=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac ba\right)$$

Since the two elements are divided with each other, the common ratio that you divide onto both of them cancels out. This is why the angle always stays the same, when you divide a vector with a scalar - that scalar simply cancels out of the angle formula.

On the examples above this becomes:

$$\text{angle}=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{40\;\mathrm m}{30\;\mathrm m}\right)=53.1^\circ \\
\text{angle}=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{15\;\mathrm m}{20\;\mathrm m}\right)=53.1^\circ$$

Comment: Thank you for typing this much for me. But we are not used to such brackets and all we have just entered to vectors and we are told coordinates are something else .THAT will be explained later probably. Summation of two components is not taught now.All I can understand is that there is some rule that  when vector divided by scaler only magnitude gets divided by scaler not the direction Am I Right ?Although I thought I could have A more satisfying answer but seeing all I have seen may be my knowledge set is not good enough to have a decent explanation

Comment: @SandeepGulati Aha, I think I understand your point a bit better now. I have updated the answer and removed some irrelevant parts that would only confuse it further. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let the vector be $\vec A = A_{\rm i}\, \hat i$ where $A_{\rm i}$ is the component of the vector in the $\hat i$ direction then $\dfrac {\vec A}{k}= \dfrac {A_{\rm i}}{k} \, \hat i$ where $k$ is a scalar.

So the value of the component of the vector is scaled but the direction of the vector stays the same.

For example $\vec A = 6 \hat i$ then $\dfrac{\vec A}{3}  = \dfrac 6 3 \hat i = 2 \hat i$

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example. Suppose I drive a car in the direction half way between north and north-east. That's the direction at 22.5 degrees from north. Let's say I went a total distance 100 km. That means I went 92.388 km north and 38.268 km east. Let's say it took 2 hours. Then my velocity had components 46.194 km/hour in the direction north, and 18.134 km/hour in the direction east. Overall, this is a vector of length 50 km/hour and direction 22.5 degrees from north.

Comment: we are not taught about components but thanks anyways for investing so much time for me